# ppActionRunMacro not working when converted to addin(ppam)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slideshow, shapes

I want to execute a piece of code when the user clicks a rectangle(shape) in the powerpoint slideshow mode .
 I added a sample code , when the shape names "timelimit" is pressed the script(macro) "correctAns" should be executed. 
This is working fine when run on the pptm file but when I converted it to ppam file(addin) it is giving the following error 
"Runtime error-2147188160 (80048240): ActionSetting(unknown member): Invalid request"

```
Sub test_action()
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("timelimit").ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionRunMacro
    .Run = "correctAns"
End With
End Sub

Sub correctAns()
    MsgBox ("correct!!!")
End Sub
```

I found some similar questions on different forums but couldn't get any solution. Please provide me some suggestions to solve this issue

Comment: You might need to install the `Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office` for assigning buttons/ribbons.

Answer (score 1):

The PPAM has no slides/shapes, so you'd need to make sure that whatever presentation you're running this in has a shape on slide 1 named "timelimit". Then you'd have the problem of getting the click action to run the macro from within the PPAM.

It'd likely be a lot simpler to add this to your presentation and save it as a PPTM:

```
Sub correctAns()
  Msgbox "correct"
End Sub
```

Then assign this as the macro to run when the shape is clicked.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have converted the pptm to ppam file and added the adding to my powerpoint application and I have opened a new ppt file added with the rectangle named "timelimit" but still it shows the same error message.

Comment: @klkl Your code in the PPAM would probably work *if* it was invoked, but as it stands, you don't seem to have any way of invoking it when the rectangle is clicked.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Rindsberg but from code point of view the actionsetting ppActionRunMacro assigns the macro (Sub routine) to that shape , and when ever the shape is clicked the macro(Sub) should get executed
But I think due to some reason the  ppActionRunMacro is not getting called(as you said) when the whole source code is converted to adding
Please let me know if I have done any mistakes,
I have one workaround of using WithEvents WindowSelectionChange to trigger the

Comment: There are no shapes in a PPA/PPAM file, so action settings assigned to shapes cannot work.

Comment: Hi Steve can you please help me with some solution/suggestions for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519638/application-event-errors-and-conflicts

Comment: I've already seen the thread, but don't have the time to debug anything that complex right now. Sorry ...